# How can the response/output of a given filter to a given sampled data be obtained in this case?

Tags: filter

There is a 1st order low-pass filter with a transfer function known as:

H(s) = 1 / (1 + s×1/ω<sub>c</sub>)

where ω<sub>c</sub> is the cut-off frequency.

I want to see the output vs input for this filter in time domain.

In this case, I can find the output if I knew the input x(t) and its Laplace transform X(s) and then I could find the Y(s) i.e the output's Laplace transform as:

Y(s) = X(s)*H(s)

where X(s) is the Laplace transform of the input x(t).

If for instance the input x(t) were a sine, I could find X(s) from the Laplace transform table and obtain Y(s). And finally I could take the inverse Laplace of Y(s) and obtain the output in time domain..

But imagine I have logged the input signal x(t) as a sampled data which became now x[n] with a sampling rate of fs. So now we don't have a continuous time signal and we also don't have the Laplace transform of this input signal.

How can we obtain the output in this case? I mean what can we do so that we can obtain the response of the LP filter to this sampled data input?

(Btw if there is another method I don't have to use Laplace transform)

Comment: Just use a simulator. You can create a user defined input and off you go.

Comment: Do you mean for instance feed the input from a sampled data text file in LTspice and obtain the output that way?

Comment: I wouldn't use LTSpice but that's the general idea.

Comment: @Andyaka It sounds like you have a personal grudge against LTspice. I, for one, have used it almost since it came out and never failed me (very rare bugs excluded).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: It's just that you don't need a circuit simulator to do IIR filtering, so using LTspice will be a lot more work than for example simply calling MATLAB's `filter()` function.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I think LTSpice is a disservice to the EE industry (it wasn't when it came out but has grown to be one). Micro-cap is far better - even the student free version - more features (like dynamic DC), easier to use, less quirky, more standard to generic Spice etc..

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree about IIR filtering, a lot easier to create filters and filter with them, but this is not the case. OP wanted an analog filter having a sampled input.

Comment: @Andyaka Of course, everyone is entitled to their opinions. I cannot say I agree with all you say, but, again, that is, largely, a matter of opinion, and it shouldn't be used as an argument to convince someone not to use it. That's all I am saying.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: An IIR *is* a computer simulation of an analog filter.  You don't need to design a circuit with the desired response and use circuit simulation tools, just recognize that the specified response is a single-pole and implement the corresponding IIR.

Comment: @BenVoigt It can be a filter of any kind, not just a translation of an analog filter. But an IIR is not a "computer simulation of an analog filter". It's a collection of poles and zeroes in the z-domain. Sure, you can simulate it on a computer, but a digital filter will never be an exact representation of an analog filter, so "implementing the corresponding IIR" is wrong. Either you use an IIR, or an analog filter. Or an infinitely sampled IIR, if you can afford. But the simulation is not an IIR, it's the result of calculations using either an IIR, or an analog filter. Also off topic. :-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen:  You're right that an IIR is not the same as an analog filter, because it works on discrete data samples not the continuous signal. But his data is already sampled; the difference is gone.  (And every time-based computer simulation of an analog filter will introduce discrete time, so is equivalent to an IIR.  Simulations in a transform domain can be different.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that would be true for an IIR filter, but OP's request is an analog filter. Since you agree an IIR is not an analog filter, the analog must be used (OP's 2nd line shows the transfer function). So his sampled data will be represented as a staircase waveform (zeroth order S&H, most probably), and the filter will ...process it somehow. And, sure, a computer simulation can come in very handy, be it SPICE simulator or Matlab/Octave/etc.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: An IIR filter is a sampled simulation of an analog filter.  Since his data is sampled, there's no better simulation possible.  So running through SPICE is a total waste.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: To be clear, the difference between the IIR and the analog filter is that the IIR has a periodic transfer function.  It cannot match the analog filter's transfer function above Fs/2.  But his sampled data is already band-limited, so there is no downside at all for using an IIR realization and not a "more accurate" simulation of an analog filter.  The "aliasing" issues that the IIR would introduce have already happened, at the data sampled stage.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you look at the 1st image in my response, would you agree that it's a (very) possible response? Not the case, anymore, true. If yes, would you agree that the sampling frequency of the IIR would have to top the data's by 8, 9, 10, or more to be meaningful? Yes, the bandwidth is lost, but it's no longer relevant, since you're no longer talking about the data's bandwidth, but of the filter's and its response. If they were the same sampling rate, yes, IIR would be just fine. Besides, can you really say that the simple schematics are that much of a hassle compared to Matlab/Octave? :-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: The filter implementation time step has to match the desired sample rate of the output data.  And yes, I'd rather type `y = filter(b, a, x);` then build a circuit and set up simulation parameters.  But then, I consider LabView "programming" to be an abomination too.  Text files can be saved to source control, rerun later, and diffed.  SPICE has textual description of the circuit, but it's an order of magnitude longer and more complex than the MATLAB IIR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you'll have a sampled waveform passing through an analog RC lowpass, which means the filter will respond with an exponential waveform until the new "step" comes in:

[image: sampledRC]

That is, it will be the response of a 1st order RC lowpass to a complex sum of square pulses.

---

Given the recent discussion in the chat, the input signal can be a 0.1Hz signal, sampled at 200Hz. The RC filter has a cutoff of 3Hz. Here's the sampled version:

[image: schematic]

The sampled input is almost a continuous waveform, due to the very high sampling rate compared to the signal. The delay is ~50.8ms.

All this could have been acomplished with a PWL source, with one catch: LTspice will display a continuous line between samples, as if a 1st order sample&hold has been used, not a 0th order one (stairs), but at this smapling rate, it shouldn't matter. If it does, though, a sample&hold can be used for the PWL source.

Comment: Thanks. But I think you misunderstood my question. I want the output response of an analog input. But the analog input I have recorded is a sampled data. This sampled data should represent the analog input. I could do it by using python's library. Actually input signal will be analog but we only have sampled. So we need the circuit to take sampled data "as if" it is analog input. Can it be done feeding the this sampled input to an RC filter from text file in LTspice?

Comment: @GenzoWakabayashi Which is exactly what I have answered. The staircase is the sampled input (V(in), blue), the smoothed waveform is the output of a 1st order RC lowpass with fc=1Hz (V(out), black). I don't know Python, but in Octave you could build the input as a normally sampled sine, `in=sin(2*pi*[0:13]/7)` (2 periods), and extend it 10 times with `(in.*ones(10,1))(:)'`, for ex. How much depends on the sampled version of your analog filter.

Comment: BTW, I used LTspice, and you can use a table made of pairs of <value, time> to make a PWL source and then feed that to whatever analog filter you want.

Comment: I understand now you smooth it. But LTspice has PWL file input. I thought it does this smoothing itself. (??) Because if I do the smoothing it will be not so good as it supposed to be.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In the screenshot, I don't use any PWL input, just a sine wave (V1) and a sample&hold (V2 and A1 -- the big symbol). G1+C1 form the equivalent of a 1st order lowpass filter with fc=1Hz. I am not sure what you mean by "[...] it does this smoothing itself". If you refer to PWL input, LTspice doesn't do any smoothing. If you refer to the waveform display, by default there is a waveform compression, but that can be omitted. You can safely use your saved x(t) data (provided you format it properly) to feed an analog filter and see the results.

Comment: No I was not talking about your screenshot. If I convert my sampled data in text file as here http://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-piecewise-linear-functions-for-voltage-current-sources.html...  And then at LTspice I use "PWL file=samples.txt" then I can process this data as if it is an analog data. That was in my mind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76024/discussion-between-a-concerned-citizen-and-genzo-wakabayashi).

Answer (score 1):

For discrete time, we typically use the [Z-Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform).

It is essentially the discrete version of the Laplace Transform. But there had to be a representation for discrete samples. The main difference, other than using the Z-Transform as a discrete method, is that the Z-Transform as a radius of convergence (ROC), meaning when you perform the summation operation, your series will converge in a particular \$z\$ value.

The Z-Transform has similar properties to that of the Laplace Transform. We notate a function of the Z-Transform as something like \$f[n]\rightarrow F(z)\$.

So

\$Y(z)=X(z)H(z)\$

If you wish, you can make \$x(t)\$ into \$x[n]\$ and the only difference is that you're saying it's a discrete function with infinitely many samples as \$\Delta n\ \rightarrow \infty\$. If you look at the Wikipedia hyperlink from the first sentence of my answer, you will see the table for Z-Transform along with its properties.

So getting back to your low pass filter. There are ways to essentially convert from Laplace Domain to the Z-Domain. This is typically converted allowing \$s=\frac{1}{T} \ln({z})\$, where \$T\$ is the sampling period. Filtering in the Z-Domain can get really messy.

When filtering in the Laplace Domain, we represent \$s\$ as \$j\omega\$... Well, in the Z-Domain, we represent \$z\$ as \$e^{j\omega}\$.

Comment: I have MATLAB as  a tool or maybe Python. Here is what I understand from you: So basically I need to find the Z-Transform of a LP filter whose cut-off freq. is given as fc. And then I  should  find the Z-Transform of my sampled data. And then multiply them and obtain Y(z). And then convert this back to the time domain by inverse Z-transform? Do you have experience with this in practice in MATLAB?

Comment: Btw does my sampled data need to be periodic for all these?

Comment: @Genzo: You can convert the filter's Z-transform directly to a time-domain implementation, which looks like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter#Direct_form_I